# Range.AutoFilter - Values Containing String

Tags: c#, .net, excel

Using an Excel VSTO Add-In, I apply a filter on a column for multiple values:

```
string[] filterTerms = { "this", "is", "sample", "text" };
Range range = Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange;
range.AutoFilter(5, filterTerms, XlAutoFilterOperator.xlFilterValues, Type.Missing, true);
```

But what I'd really like is a "Contains" filter. Take the below list:

1. Hello doesn't appear
2. **This** appears
3. **Sample** appears too
4. **Text** too

Of these, I'd like to filter for 2 / 3 / 4 because each contains a word from the array `filterTerms`.

Is there a way to accomplish this without resorting to VBA?

Comment: "Contains" can only filter up to 2 criteria.

Comment: Hmm. Are there any alternatives then?

Comment: Perhaps, without VBA it's a bit harder.  Would a pivot table work for your case?

Comment: What [about this](https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2017/05/18/excel-filter-to-match-list-of-items/)?  It looks like it supports wildcards too but I've never tried this approach.

Comment: A pivot table could work. The link you sent looks promising. Guess I could record it as a macro and run a function that way. If that's my only option, so be it. Will report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution (for now) is to limit search criteria to two values. To do this, I added wildcards to the above criteria:

```
range.AutoFilter(nameIndex, $"*{filterTerm1}*", XlAutoFilterOperator.xlFilterValues, string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterTerm2) ? Type.Missing : $"*{filterTerm2}*", true);
```

Having researched more advanced options, I came across `AdvancedFilter`, but this requires creating a `Range` of values, and from what I can tell, that involves writing values to a sheet. It would look something like this:

```
range.AdvancedFilter(XlFilterAction.xlFilterInPlace,criteriaRange, nameOfARangeOfCriteria);
```